# Django can't match url for date

Tags: regex, django, urlconf

I have a simple application and would like the home page to take a date as an url parameter.

```
url(
    regex=r'^$',
    view=HomeView.as_view(),
    name='home'
    ),
url(
    regex=r'^/(?P<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/$',
    view=HomeView.as_view(),
    name='home'
    ),
```

But when I am running (on localhost) going to 127.0.0.1:8000/08-01-2013 results in a page not found 404.  Is there something wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: That sample URL truly does not match that regexp, because you're requiring a trailing slash.  Try `/08-01-2013/`

Comment: Thanks but I tried entering that and got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [URL dispatcher docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example):

> There’s no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that. For example, it’s ^articles, not ^/articles.

So the correct regexp (since you say you don't need to break down the date components) is:

```
r'^(?P<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/$'
```

I see that falinsky's answer corrects the leading slash as well.

Comment: Thank you the leading slash is what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

instead of:

```
r'^/(?P<date>\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/$'
```

use:

```
r'^(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})-(?P<year>\d{4})/$'
```

Comment: I don't need them broken down into month day and year though I just need the date as a single string.